# In operator returns false

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Why this statement returns false? It's really weird

```
console.log("100038916831294" in ["100003748210938", "100038916831294"]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `in` operator tells you whether a value exists as a **property name** in an object. The property names of your array are "0" and "1".

You can use one of the Array methods to check if a value is in the array, like `.indexOf()` or `.includes()`:

```
console.log(["100003748210938", "100038916831294"].includes("100038916831294"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `in` operator in JavaScript compares indexes or property names in arrays instead of the value itself.

For example, if we write `console.log(0 in ["abc","pqr"]);` it will print `true`. However, if we use the value, like in `console.log("abc" in ["abc","pqr"]);` it will print `false`.

You can further read about it on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp.